# Undefined Index Upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

why it shows me this error: "Undefined index: Upload" ?

I have found many posts on this topic and have revised my code but it does not work

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" class="formphoto" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="file" name="upload" class="inputfile" id="file1">
```

Ajax

```
$('.inputfile').on('change', function(event) {

// var upload = event.target.value;

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    method: 'POST',
    url: '../MeetBlog/pages/upload_cache/upload_cache.php',
    data: new FormData($(".formphoto")[0]),
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
        $('.imgshow').html(data);
    },
    });
}); 
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/../../config/connect.php'; 

var_dump($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']);

?>
```

This comes to the Server:

[This comes to the Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9M6ag.png)

Comment: Which file / line is this error coming from?

Comment: The error is probably coming from your php file. Please share the code in php file.

Comment: Because its `upload` not `Upload`, if you try to access the file.

Comment: I added the PHP Code

Comment: did you inspect what is being sent to the server? Is it what you expect?

Comment: file uploads with ajax dont work like this

Comment: @epascarello , I added a image

Answer (score 0):

The issue lie in your php code, I've test your `html` code, excepts your code have one more `})`.

And I `print_r` `$_FILES` in my php code, which works well.

```
[2019-08-01 08:20:34][INFO] Files:--->: Array
(
    [upload] => Array
        (
            [name] => test.html
            [type] => text/html
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/php4ZbAqB
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 647
        )

)
```

```js
$('.inputfile').on('change', function(event) {
// var upload = event.target.value;
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://example.com/upload_cache.php',
    data: new FormData($(".formphoto")[0]),
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
        $('.imgshow').html(data);
    },
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" class="formphoto" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="file" name="upload" class="inputfile" id="file1">
```